# How to create multinode data center - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I successfully set up two nodes in the same Intranet. Both machines are in the same cluster. I mean they both have this property set `cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'` in the `cassandra.yaml` file. I read that this was important when linking nodes. Anyways I am extremely confused by the following guide: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted

I am trying to follow the instructions for the section, "Configuring Multinode Clusters" but there is not nearly enough detail or examples on exactly how to do this.

```
# any class that implements the SeedProvider interface and has a
# constructor that takes a Map<String, String> of parameters will do.
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "localhost"
```

Above is part of the `cassandra.yaml` file that deals with `seeds` that is mentioned in this section. I am not sure though if a) I should put my machine's IP address in the `seeds:` section or b) the remote node I am trying to connect to.

Also, this section mentions changing the `listen_address` and the `rpc_address`. However, they do not explain if the remote node I am trying to connect with should have the *listen_address* or if this address should be my own machine's waiting for tcp packets. I am likewise confused about the *rpc_address*.

Below one will find the entries in question from the `cassandra.yaml` file:

`listen_address: "localhost"`, `rpc_address: localhost`

I am using the `nodetool status` command to check if I have successfully connected to the remote node but so far the program only shows my machine and its state.

Also, I found a similar tutorial that so far also does not make much sense to me. The URL for said tutorial is here:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-multi-node-cluster-with-cassandra-on-a-ubuntu-vps

Finally, if answering this proves too difficult, less than straightforward, could someone point me in the right direction for further information on how to do this?

Thank-you for reading this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The digital ocean guide is poor. Datastax tends to have much better docs:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html

Short version:
1) Figure out how many nodes you'll have, and choose at least 1 seed IP per datacenter.

2) Setup cassandra.yaml with those IPs in the seed list. For the various _address fields, you almost never want 'localhost', and you generally want real IPs for listen_address and rpc_address (whether you do public IPs or private IPs depends on how you're doing cross-dc traffic). You'll also configure your snitch and set a few other parameters.

3) Setup cassandra-rackdc.properties, which is the file used by the 'gossiping property file snitch' (which maps IPs to datacenters, and tells cassandra how to place replicas across datacenters).

4) Start your seeds first, they'll create the cluster among themselves.

5) Start non-seed nodes one at a time, using 'nodetool status' to watch them join the ring. Don't start the next node until the joining node has status 'UN' (Up, Normal).

Comment: Is the `listen_address` the machine's IP or is it the IP of the remote machine? I also have the same question for the `rpc_address`. Also, I am only trying to connect two nodes at the present time. An answer with these things in mind would be very helpful.

Comment: I was able to solve some of this. For instance I see my remote IPs address in the seed machine's server log. My new problem is that I am receiving an error that says, `Exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException) encountered during startup: Failed to bind port 9042 on 10.xxx.xxx.xxx`.